# Running a single test several times with Gradle

Tags: testing, junit, gradle

I'm trying to migrate an Ant build script to a Gradle one and i was wondering: Is there anyway to have a test task run several times?

Comment: What's the reason for wanting to run the same tests multiple times?

Comment: We have some cases where a test fails after x amount of runs

Comment: A task can only be executed once per build execution. IMHO you should rather look into why the test fails. It sounds to me as if it either relies on a state or some external service.

Comment: It's a functionality we want to have, its not related to a specific test.

Comment: Then you should write a test that forces that to happen and validate that the last one fails. Remember that you should support test isolation, so it's no good to have test cases depend on each other, rather build one that tests the exact scenario you need. It would be helpful if you could give more detail with your question. For example, why run it several times. If you expect it to fail, why is it, what are you trying to test or expecting to achieve with such a case?

Answer (score 0):

This can be easikly done by subclassing the Test task class.

```
class StressTest extends Test {
    // can be overwritten from within the task call
    int times = 5
    public FileTree getCandidateClassFiles() {
        FileTree candidates = super.getCandidateClassFiles()
        for (int i = 1; i < times; i++) {
            candidates = candidates + super.getCandidateClassFiles()
        }
        return candidates
    }
}

task stressTest(type: StressTest) {
    // run test 10 times
    times = 10
}
```

Inspired by Rene Groeschke, https://gist.github.com/breskeby/836316