# Running TestNG tests multiple times

Tags: java, gradle, testng, stress-testing

I want to implement some sort of stress-testing using Gradle and TestNG / JUnit.

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/41650455 which is working perfectly fine with JUnit, but it does not work with TestNG. I created a small repo to show my issue:

https://github.com/dhardtke/gradle-testng-stresstest

If I run `gradlew stressTestJUnit` I correctly receive

```
JUnitTests > testNothing STANDARD_ERROR
    I am a JUnit test!

JUnitTests > testNothing STANDARD_ERROR
    I am a JUnit test!

JUnitTests > testNothing STANDARD_ERROR
    I am a JUnit test!

JUnitTests > testNothing STANDARD_ERROR
    I am a JUnit test!

JUnitTests > testNothing STANDARD_ERROR
    I am a JUnit test!
```

but when running `gradlew stressTestTestNG` I only receive:

```
Gradle suite > Gradle test > TestNGTests.testNothing STANDARD_ERROR
    I am a TestNG test!
```

I already tried figuring out what Gradle does differently when executing TestNG tests instead of JUnit tests, but couldn't figure it out (yet): https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/testing-jvm/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/testing/testng

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out how to do this:

build.gradle:

```
task testNG(type: StressTest) {
    useTestNG() {
        options.listeners << "core.test.TestNgStressTestListener"
        environment "times", times
        environment "stressTest", true
    }
}
```

and my `TestNgStressTestListener` class:

```
@Override
public void alter(final List<XmlSuite> suites) {
    final boolean stressTest = Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getenv("stressTest"));

    if (stressTest) {
        final int times = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("times"));

        final XmlSuite base = suites.get(0);
        suites.clear();
        final String baseName = base.getName();

        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            final XmlSuite copy = (XmlSuite) base.clone();
            copy.setName(String.format("%s (%d)", baseName, i + 1));

            suites.add(copy);
        }
    }
}
```

The given listener just duplicates the first `XmlSuite` and alters its name (otherwise an Exception is thrown inside of TestNG).

Works like a charm!