# Running the same Gradle task multiple times

Tags: java, testing, gradle, junit

So i have a gradle test task which runs all my tests. How can I set up gradle to run this task 100 times? It works and runs all my tests, I just need an option to choose how many times to run this.

The task in build.gradle:

```
test {
    // enable JUnit Platform (a.k.a. JUnit 5) support
    useJUnitPlatform()

    // set a system property for the test JVM(s)
    systemProperty 'some.prop', 'value'

    // explicitly include or exclude tests
    include 'com/company/calculator/**'

    // show standard out and standard error of the test JVM(s) on the console
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

    // set heap size for the test JVM(s)
    minHeapSize = "128m"
    maxHeapSize = "512m"

    // set JVM arguments for the test JVM(s)
    jvmArgs '-XX:MaxPermSize=256m'

    // listen to events in the test execution lifecycle
    beforeTest { descriptor ->
        logger.lifecycle("Running test: " + descriptor)
    }

    // Fail the 'test' task on the first test failure
    failFast = true

    // listen to standard out and standard error of the test JVM(s)
    onOutput { descriptor, event ->
        logger.lifecycle("Test: " + descriptor + " produced standard out/err: " + event.message )
    }
```

The use case is that i want to test performance of different assertions and mocking libraries (i have multiple branches with tests written using different libraries), to do that i need to run test suite multiple times.

To test performance i need to measure the time it takes to run these tests for example 100 times (maybe 1000), on each libraries set.

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Use a proper microbenchmarking tool, like [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), instead of running Gradle task 100+ times. Or use [@Repeated tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-repeated-tests).

Comment: @madhead Thank you:) @ Repeated tests is what i needed i think

Comment: The downside of repeated test is that you fall down to a single configuration at the time of the execution.
If you want different test configurations without changing the architecture (singletons, caches, etc.) of the project, you'll need to rerun the tests from the outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option might be this --rerun-tasks flag.
`gradle test --rerun-tasks`
From [the Gradle user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html).

Another option, from a similar question, is creating a subclass of the Test class that returns a task with multiple copies of all tests, code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41650455/1686615 .

There really are many ways to do this at different levels, with Gradle code as in that link, or perhaps in .gradle files, with a parameter passed into the test code, or on the command line.  Maybe indicate more about your use case or if there is a particular level at which you'd like to make the change.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I updated question with my use case

Comment: any idea how to do that?

Comment: `--rerun-tasks` doesn't run test multiple times, but rather reruns it's tasks dependencies even if not neede.

Comment: Yep, as @AlikElzin-kilaka comments `--rerun-tasks` supports running tests multiple times without make clean'ing. It does not run the tests multiple times, so multiple calls are still needed, for example a script like:

`gradle test # initial build` 
`date +%s # print start time` 
`for i in {1..100}; do gradle test --rerun-tasks; done` 
`date +%s # print end time`

Comment: Running all the other not-needed tasks is a huge waste. I do this with a loop in my shell and have not found a better answer.